# Amazon simple email service converts html tags

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, email, html-email, amazon-ses

I have a java application that uses *Amazon SES* for email.
The email template is constructed within the Java application.
I needed to add a image link to the email template and I added a standard email IMG tag like below

```
<img src="<PATH TO THE IMAGE OMITED>" alt="alt text omitted" >
```

But when the email comes through, rather than show the image, I see the HTML code on the email body.
When I look at the email source I see the `'<', '>'` and and quote signs have been converted like below.

```
<p>
THIS IS AN AUTO-GENERATED EMAIL. DO NOT REPLY.
</p>&lt;img src=&quot;<a href="https://protect-au.mimecast.com/s/VywertyMqHLlkUn?domain=blah.com">https://IMAGE_PATH OMMITTED.png</a>&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; &gt;
```

It seems *Amazon SES* is converting some of the tags within the image bot not the ahref tags.

This was tested on a local email server and a fake smtp server and there was no conversion happening.

*Amazon SES* is setup on a client environment and I have no direct access to it.

What could be causing this? Could you please point in the likely direction.

Comment: Did you put the `<a href="...">` in there or is that coming from Amazon SES? (That should be around the img if you want a link on the image, `<a href="..."><img ...></a>`)

Comment: Thanks @Nathan . I did not put the href, but it looks like mimecast added it. And seemingly mimecast is converting the html symbols.

Comment: Long shot, but, images are naturally inline. Maybe it needs a `<p>` tag or `<td>` tag around it? Alternatively, perhaps it has something to do with the Doctype--try a different one (can control how things get interpreted)? Maybe also it was expecting `/>` closing tag.